# Can I use cgo with Windows SDK?

Tags: go, cgo

I've just tried tdm-gcc and it works, but is it possible to use cgo with Windows SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cgo is supported on Windows.

There are still some [open issues](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list?q=label%3aos-windows) you might want to take a look at, though.  I believe there are also [some fixes](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/golang-nuts/cgo%2420windows/golang-nuts/uYw2d-xxY3k/7MoxYOsBN_EJ) in place since go1, so you may need to work from closer to tip (I can't recall if they're in go1.0.3 or not).